# Creating a function with a list as an input

Tags: list-manipulation

I have to create a function that takes a list as its input.  The conditions are as follows: if the list contains a 1 before a 2, the output should be a new list where the 1 and the 2 have changed places.  If the list does not contain a 1 before a 2, the output should be the original list.

I'm looking to use the SequenceReplace function, but can't get it to work yet. I have the following:

```
f[x_] := SequenceReplace[x, {{1, x} -> 2, {1} -> 2, {2, x} -> 1, {2} -> 1}]
```

I don't know how to get it to work after this; this code switches the 1 and 2, but I don't know how to include the fact that the 1 and 2 should only switch if 1 comes before 2 in the list.

Answer (score 7):

```
ClearAll[f]
f[x_List] := SequenceReplace[x, {1, 2} -> Sequence[2, 1]]

f[{5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 6, 2}]
```

> {5, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 6, 2}

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 6, 2};
```

Using `SequencePosition` and `SubsetMap` (new in 12.0)

```
p = Flatten @ SequencePosition[list, {1, 2}]
```

{2, 3, 10, 11}

```
SubsetMap[Reverse, p] @ list
```

{5, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 6, 2}

```
SwapPairs[list_, pair_] :=
 With[{p = Flatten @ SequencePosition[list, pair]},
  SubsetMap[Reverse, list, p]]
```

Swap one pair

```
SwapPairs[list, {6, 2}]
```

{5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 6}

Swap several pairs

```
Fold[SwapPairs, list, {{1, 2}, {6, 2}}]
```

{5, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 6}

Answer (score 1):

```
l = {5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 6, 2};
```

---

Using `SequencePosition` and `ReplacePart`:

```
SwapPairs[lst_, pair_] := 
With[{p = SequencePosition[lst, pair]}, 
ReplacePart[lst, 
Splice@*Thread /@ Thread[# -> Array[Reverse[pair] &, Length@#] &@p]]]
```

---

Swap one pair:

```
SwapPairs[l, {6, 2}]
```

*Result*:

> {5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 6}

Swap several pairs:

```
Fold[SwapPairs, l, {{1, 2}, {6, 2}}]
```

*Result*:

> {5, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 6}